# Using abstract classes and Android Activities

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity

I have several activities that have similar behaviors I have created a base activity class to serve as the parent for each class where common elements and methods can be implemented.

```
public abstract class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public Class<AppCompatActivity> actRoot;

    void btnCancel(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, actRoot);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I then go on to define a child class as follows

```
public void ChildActivity extends ParentActivity{
     @Overide
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
         actRoot = MainActivity.class;
     }
}
```

Act root can be any child or grandchild of `AppCompatActivity`.

How can I define a class reference to be used dynamically as a relative of a `AppCompatActivity` in this context?

Comment: Why do you need to have a class reference of all your subclassed activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach might not be advisable but if you wanted to try it you would use this instead:

```
public Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> actRoot;
```

and then later:

```
actRoot = MainActivity.class;
```

Comment: Could you provide a specific or list of specific reasons why the approach is not advisable so that I can refactor the question?

Your code does seem work so If the original question is valid you have the answer.

Comment: It depends on what the purpose of `actRoot` is and it is hard to tell in your example. I said it might not be advisable because in your example you are starting an activity using `actRoot` when a cancel button is clicked. The typical thing to do in that case would be to finish the current activity and let the previous activity on the back stack if there is one come back as if the user pressed the back button.

Comment: Thanks I think that may have answered another question I had. I am going to think about  it for a min then update the code to reflect this in the question.

Comment: Since this has answered your original question it might be best to create a new question for the next before things get too off topic.

Comment: I just corrected the main code to be a better example of coding the reason I was doing it wrong is I followed directions in another post, out of context. Does that clean up the code?

Comment: That again depends on the usage. You need to be aware of what [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) does and decide if it makes sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's such a good idea to do so. If you have so much classes that you can't define each one of them statically, it's probably that you've missed some other way to factorise your code.

I'll answer anyway : you could use a [delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern), which the linked wikipedia article will explain better than I could.